# Is a language L = {s ∈ (0 + 1)* | d(s) mod 5 =2 and d(s) mod 7 !=4 } regular?

Tags: regular-language, dfa

While reading from a book I had this doubt.

It mentions that

L = {s ∈ (0+1)* | n0(s) mod 7 = n1(s) mod5 =0} is regular
Where n0(s) = number of 0’s in s and n1(s) = number of 1’s in s

Further it mentions that

L = {s ∈ (0 + 1)* | d(s) mod 5 =2 and d(s) mod 7 !=4 } is not regular (not even context-free but it is recursive)
Where d(s) = decmial value of s (e.g. d(101) = 5)

Why is it so? Is it because a DFA doesn’t have memory to store (remember) the decimal value of s? But in that case how come the first language is given to be regular?

Comment: Should be on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @nightcracker: no, it should not. Please check cstheory's FAQ.

Comment: Should probably be on Math.SE.

Comment: It seems you intend d(s) to be the value of s as a *binary* number, nothing to do with decimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is either a mistake in your textbook or you are misreading it: the second language you name is regular.

A DFA can compute the value of a binary number (or any base number) modulo *m* (for any *m*). Simply have *m* states numbered 0 to *m*-1; when reading a zero, go from the current state *s* to (*s**2) mod *m*; when reading a one, go to (*s**2+1) mod *m*. To see that this works, one needs only to look at how binary works, and that (*a* + *b*) mod *m* = (*a* mod *m* + *b* mod *m*) mod *m* (and similarly for multiplication).

To accept numbers which are equal to *k* mod *m*, make *k* an accepting state; to accept numbers different from *k* mod *m*, make all other states accepting.
This means {s ∈ {0,1}* | d(s) mod 5 = 2} and {s ∈ {0,1}* | d(s) mod 7 != 4 } are both regular languages. The language *L* is their intersection, and the regular languages are closed under intersection, so *L* is regular.

The language {s ∈ {0,1}* | d(s) mod 5 = 2} is accepted by the regular expression '(((0*10(10*10)*10*11|0*11)((00|1)(10*10)*10*11|01)*(00|1)(10*10)*0|0*10(10*10)*0)(0((00|1)(10*10)*10*11|01)*(00|1)(10*10)*0|1)*0((00|1)(10*10)*10*11|01)*(00|1)(10*10)*|(0*10(10*10)*10*11|0*11)((00|1)(10*10)*10*11|01)*(00|1)(10*10)*|0*10(10*10)*)$' (I have used Python notation here, but to obtain your notation simply replace | by + and remove the $).